# PHP-FPM user permissions after restart

Tags: php, mac-osx, php-fpm

For some reason after I restart php-fpm daemon, files that were generated using PHP (Twig templating cache) aren't accessible by PHP anymore. I think it's something to do with php-fpm user/group (_www/_www).

```
Unable to write in the cache directory (/Users/iber/Work/Projects/Work/app/public/assets/compile/3f/87)
```

The only solution is completely remove the folder contents and reload the page for Twig to compile the files again.

`compile` directory has `0777` permissions.

`php-fpm(v5.5)` was installed through homebrew.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: I just uncommented `listen.owner = _www` and `listen.group = _www` in php-fpm.ini and it worked..

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault!  If you found a solution to your problem (and it looks like you did), you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.  That way people finding this later will see that there's a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to answer my own question.

Even though php-fpm.ini had

```
user = _www
group = _www
```

It appears that by default installation these lines were commented out:

```
listen.owner = _www
listen.group = _www
```

I've uncommented them and it worked.